# What is the exponential series representation of $x^x$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I want to express $x^x$ in the form of an infinite series involving $qe^{sx}$ where $q$ is the $s$th coefficient of the series and $s$ is the power on $e^x$. Beyond just an answer I would like to know how it is derived.

The only solution I can think of is curve fitting an exponential form and using regression or developing a new definition of the derivative which outputs the coefficient of the closest fitting exponential function as opposed to line.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: So you want to find coefficients $c_0, c_1, c_2 \ldots$ such that $x^x = c_0 e^0 + c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{2x} + \ldots$?

Comment: @george exactly!

Comment: Well, if $g(x) = x^{\log{\log{x}}} = e^{(\log{x})(\log{\log{x}})}$, then $g(e^x) = x^x$. So if you find the Taylor expansion for $g$, and if it converges for a suitable radius, then you can just substitute $e^x$ for $x$ in its terms. I don't think that the Taylor expansion will be pretty though...

Comment: A serious difficult with this is, as other responders have pointed out, that $x^x$ grows faster than any "exponential growth" function.  Moreover, $(x^x)'  =  (x^x) \cdot (1 + \ln x)$; its derivative grows faster than the function itself, so I don't think something like a power series will be applicable (I believe it would have a radius of convergence of zero?).  If that doesn't work, probably what you are asking for doesn't work either.

Comment: well we do have to note that: e^x grows much fast than any polynomial... and all of the derivatives of e^x grow faster than polynomials as well yet still there exists a taylor approximation for e^x

Comment: I checked on wolfram and found that x^x can be expressed trivially as e^(ln(x))^x meaning that the definition of e^x with x*ln(x) subsituted in place of x creates a convergent series

Comment: so the answer is Sum(i = 0, inf)[x^i*ln(x)^i/i!] but this doesn't solve the problem in terms of exponentials as I had desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is no series of the kind you want.  But you will have to be more precise in order to be sure.  My thought is: as $x\to\infty$ we have  $x^x$ grows much faster than $e^{sx}$ for any $s \in \mathbb R$.
$$
 x^x \gg e^{s x}
$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure x^x > e^x for x > e